# Data collector: how much power will my system use (Linux vs. RTOS)?

Tags: embedded, linux, power-consumption, freertos, rtos

This is about a data collection device. It mainly contains a Linux operating system, various data interfaces such as RS232/RS485/CAN/SDI-12/RJ45, etc., and a communication module for 4G and satellite communication. Of course, there are some analog ADC conversion circuits.

I am using an NXP i.MX 6ULL series chip at 900 MHz main frequency.

I would like to know how much more power I will consume with a LINUX system than with a real-time OS like FreeRTOS.

Comment: Do you need an OS at all?

Comment: that depend on what the RJ45 needs to do.

Comment: the wording of your question indicates that you are looking for near exact values ... you will have to measure them

Comment: Do you need 900MHz clock and an OS at all? A lot of data collection is the domain of relatively simple microcontrollers, and what you describe seems to be slow stuff that doesn't need much fancy. Some buffers, interrupt service routines/dma setup, and the data is flowing from input to output, even with some mild processing in-between. Doesn't seem like anything that needs multiple tasks with priorities, etc. You'd probably need to describe exactly the inputs, data rates, and processing you need to do. I have systems in the field that do this sort of data collection on relatively slow MCUs.

Comment: Not that there's anything wrong with having lots and lots of cycles available. The more the merrier. Running a 900MHz chip at a low duty cycle due to low workload is very good from a power perspective. If the peripherals can run without attention from the core most of the time, that is. But if all you need is a TCP/IP stack, then it doesn't necessarily take an RTOS. In fact, a single-thread implementation with everything explicitly handled in a sequential manner is much easier to reason about and has less potential for bugs.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time for me to use the English community to ask questions, and I am not familiar with many functions.

Comment: The reason why I choose OS and this chip is that I think in the field that our company is engaged in, although the equipment is simply collecting and storing a large amount of data without processing it, I anticipate that in the future, many devices will be combined with automation and AI. I think it is a good thing to leave sufficient performance.

Comment: Moreover, leaders do not have high requirements on the cost of the equipment, which will eventually be provided to the government meteorological department. What he cared about was the minimum power squeeze I could do with this system, which was hard for me to estimate as a college senior who had not yet graduated.

Comment: This device will eventually be deployed in the field in an unoccupied place to monitor the weather elements of that location, such as temperature and pressure and dozens of other parameters. It uses a combination of solar and wind power to supply electricity, so if it can achieve a long operating time, then this will give the product a very good competitive edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference in power usage will be mostly defined by how efficiently you are managing device power states, including those of your CPU, and that is more dependent on driver support than the system core.

Your system needs a model of dependencies between devices (e.g. "the USB controller needs to be active for 4G to work"), and a policy to set the power levels so that your application can still work.

You want to reduce your CPU clock, possibly core voltage as well, and turn off any radio functions you are not currently using, that are the biggest items.

Communication uses magnitudes more power than anything else in the system, so you need a way to turn those components off for as long as possible. If a daily report is sufficient, turn on the radio once a day, if you need to receive commands, investigate if it is sufficient to check for commands once every hour, or if you can use a more lightweight protocol.

Once that is done, the other thing to look into is "tickless idle" mode, where the CPU will not even set a periodic timer to switch tasks and advance the clock, so ideally the CPU is turned off between collection of data points.

If the choice of CPU is not fixed yet, a slower and smaller CPU might also make a difference.

Comment: Your suggestion is very useful, I think I can do a more in-depth study on the management strategy of the communication system, and then go to my superiors to give a reply, thanks again.